# Get resource id from content://settings/system/ringtone?

Tags: android, uri, ringtone

When I pick the default ringtone, I get a `Uri` with path `content://settings/system/ringtone`. So there is no path ending with integer, as in returning a usual rintone (for example, `content://media/internal/audio/media/38`).

How can I now get a resource id from this default ringtone? Any parsing is impossible since there is no any integer identification.

Answer (score 4):

If your check the setting db, you will find the content save to setting db is media uri. That means below uri actually is a map to media uri.

From:

```
content://settings/system/ringtone
```

To:

```
content://media/internal/audio/media/38
```

So you need to write a converter to do it:

```
   public Uri uriMap(Uri uri) {
        Uri mediaUri = uri;
        if(uri.getAuthority().equals(Settings.AUTHORITY)) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri,new String[]{
                        Settings.NameValueTable.VALUE},null,null,null);
                if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String val = c.getString(0);
                    mediaUri = Uri.parse(val);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"" + uri + "->" + mediaUri);
        return mediaUri;
    }
```